# Python script not executing from Windows Task Schedular

Tags: python, windows

We have installed python on Windows server at C:\ by logging in with a special user account. The .py script also resides there. When the .py script is executed through command prompt, it runs successfully. The environment variables are created under that specific user account but not as a system variable.

When trying to schedule with Task Scheduler( by checking whether the user is logged in or out) with a different user account, It doesn't execute the script. The password doesn't change for the account we are trying to execute with Task scheduler, hence using this account.

Does the environmental variable needs to be added to system variable? or are we missing something?

Can you please provide any insights on how to make this work? Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to have more information regarding the configuration of the scheduled task. Could you please provide details on how you created the task using Task Scheduler? Additionally, any error messages or logs that were encountered would be useful in troubleshooting the issue. It would also be helpful to know more about the Python script you are trying to execute, including any dependencies or external resources it relies on. With these details, we can provide better insights and assistance.

Comment: It was configured as  C:\python.exe in program and "C:\<filename>.py" in Arguments in the task. When the user that installed the python tried this: The python script is good as it was run successfully from command prompt. The script makes a REST API call and gets the data. The data is getting successfully inserted into the tables when the py script is called manually from the command prompt.

Comment: But when the Task scheduler is triggered with a different user account(this user account has password that is constant, so we can schedule the task whether the user is logged in or not ). It doesn't do anything. No errors. It says the job is completed, but no data is getting inserted.

Comment: So if you manually run it as the different user account, as opposed to via the task scheduler, what happens?